# how to read the subfolder of inbox in outlook via pop3 using java mail API?

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail, pop3

I am using JavaMail API to connect official outlook account. I have list of sub folders (labels) under INBOX in my outlook account which I created. How can I list all the available sub folders of INBOX (the user created)?

Using this method:

```
Folder[] list = store.getDefaultFolder().list();
```

I am getting only INBOX folder in pop3.Is there any other method to get the list of sub folders available in a mail account?

Comment: POP3 doesn't have subfolders of anything, let alone the INBOX. You seem to be wanting IMAP features over POP3. which does not compute.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible with POP3. The POP3 protocol only gives you access to your inbox folder. See also the JavaMail FAQ entry [*"How do I access or create folders other than INBOX on my POP3 server?"*](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#pop3folder):

> Q: How do I access or create folders other than INBOX on my POP3 server?
>   A: You can't. POP3 servers only support a single mailbox per user.
>   Most mail readers that use POP3 also maintain a local message store
>   into which they copy incoming messages (from the POP3 INBOX) and allow
>   you to file messages in other folders. See [this item](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#localprovs) for more
>   information about local store providers.

In other words, if you want to access other folders, then you will need to use the IMAP protocol (and not POP3).

Comment: But i cannot access outlook mail using IMAP, it can be read only using POP3. Is there any way to access outlook using IMAP instead of POP3, so that i can read sub folders also.

Comment: @Gowthamn Exactly what do you mean with Outlook? Outlook is a program in the office suite, it is not a mail server so you can't connect to it with either POP3 or IMAP at all. Are you talking about Microsoft Exchange? That supports IMAP (if enabled by the server admin). Or are you talking about outlook.com? That supports IMAP as well, see [POP, IMAP, and SMTP settings for Outlook.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-IMAP-and-SMTP-settings-for-Outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040)